# Split array into evenly sized arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to split an array into 3 even arrays. So far I have only found examples of chunking into specified array lengths. For example:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const results = [];

while (array.length) {
  results.push(array.splice(0, 3));
}

return results; //returns [1,2,3],[4,5]
```

So if i had `array = [1,2,3,4,5]` (or any other length)

I need to split this into `[1,2], [3,4], [5]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the size of the chunks by dividing the length by 3:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const results = [];

const chunkSize = Math.ceil(array.length / 3);
while (array.length) {
  results.push(array.splice(0, chunkSize));
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: `splice()` will also modify the contents of the original array.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari : OP hasn't done that in immutable way either, however, shallow copy may be done in advance to avoid mutation, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the array and use a size for adding the wanted lengths.

This approach does not mutate the given data.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    results = [],
    size = Math.ceil(array.length / 3),
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) results.push(array.slice(i, i += size));

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this in this you need to provide the number of a chunk

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const chunk = (input, nos) => {
    let size = Math.ceil(input.length/nos);
    return input.reduce((arr, item, idx) => {
      return idx % size === 0
          ? [...arr, [item]]
          : [...arr.slice(0, -1), [...arr.slice(-1)[0], item]];
      }, []);
};


console.log(chunk(arr, 3));
```